# Calculations between different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I try to run loop over a pandas dataframe that takes two arguments from different rows. I tried to use .iloc and shift functions but did not manage to get the result i need.
Here's a simple example to explain better what i want to do:

dataframe1:

```
     a  b    c
0  101  1  aaa
1  211  2  dcd
2  351  3  yyy
3  401  5  lol
4  631  6  zzz
```

for the above df I want to make new column ('d') that gets the diff between the values in column 'a' only if the diff between the values in column 'b' is equal to 1, if not the value should be null. like the following  dataframe2:

```
     a  b    c  d
0  101  1  aaa  nan
1  211  2  dcd  110
2  351  3  yyy  140
3  401  5  lol  nan
4  631  6  zzz  230
```

Is there any designed function that can handle this kind of calculations?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this, using `loc` and [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
df.loc[df.b.diff() == 1, 'd'] = df.a.diff()
>>> df
     a  b    c      d
0  101  1  aaa    NaN
1  211  2  dcd  110.0
2  351  3  yyy  140.0
3  401  5  lol    NaN
4  631  6  zzz  230.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a group key

```
df1.groupby(df1.b.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).a.diff()
Out[361]: 
0      NaN
1    110.0
2    140.0
3      NaN
4    230.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```